# Overlapping administrative units - excel associations

Tags: microsoft-excel, list

In excel, I have a list of administrative units and need to find the overlapping relationship between the tax districts that comprise the administrative units. In column A I have the administrative unit, and in column B I have the tax district. I'm working with over 10,000 tax districts.

Given an administrative unit (Column A), I can easily return a list of the tax districts that comprise it (Column B). However, I need to also determine what other administrative unit a given tax district falls in. As in: After selecting an administrative unit in Column A which returns a list of tax districts from Column B, how can I find the other administrative units in Column A that are tied to those tax districts?

```
+-------------------------+--------------+
| Administrative unit     | Tax District |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| Columbiana County       | Butler       |
| Columbiana County       | Center       |
| Columbiana County       | Elkrun       |
| East Liverpool City     | Butler       |
| East Liverpool City     | Center       |
| Salem City              | Elkrun       |
| Crestview Schools       | Butler       |
| Crestview Schools       | Center       |
| United Local Schools    | Elkrun       |
| East Columbiana Library | Butler       |
| East Columbiana Library | Elkrun       |
| West Columbiana Library | Center       |
+-------------------------+--------------+
```

For example, all of the Schools overlap with the county because each of the 3 tax districts also fall in the county. However, Crestview Schools overlaps with East Liverpool City due to the association with Butler and Center. Crestview Schools does not overlap with Salem City because Butler and Center do not fall in Salem City.

Crestview Schools would have both Libraries as overlapping: East Columbiana (because of Butler) and West Columbiana (because of Center).

Comment: Can you show us the expected output?

Comment: Based on your example, why are only *East Columbiana* and *West Columbiana* overlapping ***Crestview Schools***? Don't *Columbiana County* and *East Liverpool City* also have those Butler and Center districts?

Comment: Yes, so the process would look something like this:
1. Select Crestview Schools (I have a dropdown list for this)
2. Output: 
    Columbiana County
    East Liverpool City
    East Columbiana Library
    West Columbiana Library
    Butler
    Center

Comment: The whole output (`Columbiana County East Liverpool City East Columbiana Library West Columbiana Library Butler Center` in one cell? Or the units list and district list in two cells?

Comment: I would need a list with unit in it's own cell. I am currently making progress using the FILTER formula but can't determine how to advance the formula to pull from each subsequent Tax District.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1786556/edit) instead of adding information in comments

Comment: I still don't understand very well how you want the output. Something like this would be good https://imgur.com/1Zd36dh?

Comment: Or maybe like this? https://imgur.com/2aegbsa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your goal, you could use the `LET()` function to achieve this. Assuming your data is stored in the range `A1:B13` and for the moment a hard-coded lookup value, which can simply be changed to the cell where you have the drop-down list. The procedure looks as follows:

```
=LET(
admin_lookup, "Crestview Schools",
data, A2:B13,
tax_filtered, FILTER(INDEX(data,, 2), INDEX(data,, 1) = admin_lookup),
admin_filtered, UNIQUE(FILTER(INDEX(data,, 1), ISNUMBER(MATCH(INDEX(data,, 2), tax_filtered, 0)))),
result, FILTER(admin_filtered, admin_filtered <> admin_lookup),
result
)
```

First, you initialize the admin_lookup value, e.g., "Crestview School". Then you initialize your data range and from there everything is referring to these aspects such that it is dynamic. Based on the admin_lookup value, you first want to filter the respective tax_districts, which then serve as the input to filter the admin_units, that have this tax_district. Given that the tax_districts are not a single value but an array, you can combine the `ISNUMBER()` and `MATCH()` functions to correctly filter for the entire array. In the end, you additionally filter out the admin_lookup value, such that it is only the list with the admin_units it interacts with and then return the result.

The output looks as follows for three examples:

| Columbiana County | Crestview Schools | Salem City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| East Liverpool City | Columbiana County | Columbiana County |
| Salem City | East Liverpool City | United Local Schools |
| Crestview Schools | East Columbiana Library | East Columbiana Library |
| United Local Schools | West Columbiana Library |  |
| East Columbiana Library |  |  |
| West Columbiana Library |  |  |

---

**Extension 1:**

In case you want to return it as, e.g., a comma separated list, you could include the `TEXTJOIN()` function as follows (replacing the current filter statement for the result):

```
result, TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, FILTER(admin_filtered, admin_filtered <> admin_lookup)),
```

The result for "Crestview Schools" will look then as follows:

```
Columbiana County, East Liverpool City, East Columbiana Library,
West Columbiana Library
```

**Extension 2:**

In case you want to return not only the final filtered admin_units, but also the intermediate filtered tax_districts, you can include the `HSTACK()` function in combination with `IFERROR()` (to avoid "#N/A" values) at the end of the `LET()` statement.

```
IFERROR(HSTACK(tax_filtered;result);"")
```

The result for "Crestview Schools" will then look as follows:

| Crestview Schools |  |
| --- | --- |
| Butler | Columbiana County |
| Center | East Liverpool City |
|  | East Columbiana Library |
|  | West Columbiana Library |

Comment: Thank you so much.